# NativeScript Sidekick - CLI is required (version 5.1.1)

Tags: nativescript

I recently got noticed in the Sidekick application on mac OS that a new version of the CLI was released and that I needed to update.

I quit Sidekick and run the "sudo tns i -g nativescript@latest --unsafe-perm" command in terminal with the following results:

```
+ nativescript@5.1.1
updated 67 packages in 14.325s
```

When I try to start Sidekick I get the following error:
[Sidekick prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTUhM.png)

I head back to terminal and run "tns doctor" with the following results:

```
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 10.1.0 satisfies minimum required version 9.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
⚠ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 5.1.0 and the latest available version is 5.1.1.
```

It seems like the update are not recognized by either **tns doctor** or **Sidekick**, what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `nvm`? This can happen when the settings in terminal are different from the global ones. For example it is possible to use one node version in the terminal and other from globally installed Sidekick.

Comment: I do not have nvm installed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `sudo` - see [this blog post](https://www.competa.com/blog/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/) on details on how to resolve the issue by removing the need for superuser while doing NPM installs. Similar thread [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4195#issuecomment-443991942)

Comment: I'll have to check that out when I'm in front of my Mac again. Will come back with the results

Answer (score 0):

On tns doctor command we got this message: `Getting NativeScript components versions information...`
This after tried to update with: `sudo npm install nativescript -g --unsafe-perm`
after that we got a lot of error messages.
Solved with this simply command: 
`tns proxy clear` 
then run: `sudo npm install nativescript -g --unsafe-perm`
Solved!